# How can I add GA4 exploration to the Report Dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have created a new GA4 exploration that provides: Countries, Regions, and New Users.
Everything was perfectly done, but now I didn't know how to show/add this exploration report on the main GA4 Report Dashboard.

Any idea, please?

I have checked many YouTube videos, articles and yet didn't get a solution.

Comment: No you can not. You need to set the report again in the custom setting report. Explorer is kind of an individual feature.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try set the report in the custom setting.